# apple mach-o linker error linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, linker

[image]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMAAm.png)I am working with Objective C with core data, I got an error:

Apple Mach-O Linker Error, Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)[image]

Comment: i faced this when added a pod twice

Answer (score 5):

You need open detail description.

[image: step image]

Comment: you need check somewhere have duplicate file.

Comment: In my case there are duplicate files. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Check if you have imported a .m file instead if .h somewhere in your project.

Another thing to look for is the import of a header file twice.

If the above two don't work Select your project -> Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries. Go through the list and see if a framework is added more than once.

Comment: Did you check it ? Give it a try.

Comment: If you're using react-native and seeing duplicate symbols, you may have added a library twice, once manually and once with the react-native link command.

Comment: @GvSharma: Which option?

Comment: @GvSharma:Sorry, It's in project -> Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries

Answer (score 1):

It's because the project inserted the core data's xcdatamodeld file in ***compile sources.***
Select your project -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources and delete ***projectName.xcdatamodeld*** file.
Just try it and reply me if still any error.

Answer (score 0):

importing .m file instead of .h file can cause this error