# yarn run ios error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65

Tags: react-native

this is very basic error and it is already ask in stackoverflow and i tried all solution but it is not working in my project.

1. pod install in ios folder.

when i run command yarn run android it is run successfully but when i run yarn run ios command it throws error  Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening AwesomeProject1.xcworkspace. .

dependencies:  "react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "^0.63.4",

Comment: open your project in xcode via `AwesomeProject1.xcworkspace` and then run (clean build folder before). It will work.

Comment: Thank u for your response but when i am try this things it gives error when build project- 'event2/event-config.h' file not found

Comment: check this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30836#issuecomment-772810588

Comment: now it error throw  Apple Mach-O Linker Error (Linker error failed with exit code 1)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43975793/apple-mach-o-linker-error-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see

Comment: check this as well https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30836#issuecomment-772830882

Comment: still not error solved  error Apple Mach-O Linker Error (Linker error failed with exit code 1)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, but it works when I run `npx react-native run-ios` instead of `yarn`.